# How to check if a file is not empty in Batch

Tags: windows, batch-file

There are several ways google throws at me for checking if a file is empty but I need to do the opposite.

```
If (file is NOT empty)

do things
```

How would I do this in batch?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
for /f %%i in ("file.txt") do set size=%%~zi
if %size% gtr 0 echo Not empty
```

Comment: returns: >>unexpected 0

Comment: @Tertium - The fix is to add `set size=0` on the line before the `for` loop.

Comment: @Tertium I think you forgot the double quotes in for /f %%i in ("file.txt") - that's what I did and adding them back fixed the problem

Comment: Quick fix for if that returns an empty result, but a leading 0, like: if 0%size% GTR 0 echo Not empty

Answer (score 8):

this should work:

```
for %%R in (test.dat) do if not %%~zR lss 1 echo not empty
```

`help if` says that you can add the `NOT` directly after the `if` to invert the compare statement

Comment: shouldn't there be a Switch after if like: for %%R in (test.dat) do if /i not %%~zR EQU 0 echo not empty

Answer (score 4):

```
set "filter=*.txt"
for %%A in (%filter%) do if %%~zA==0 echo."%%A" is empty
```

Type `help for` in a command line to have explanations about the ~zA part

Answer (score 4):

You can leverage subroutines/external batch files to get to useful [parameter modifiers](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/percent.mspx?mfr=true) which solve this exact problem

```cmd
@Echo OFF
(Call :notEmpty file.txt && (
    Echo the file is not empty
)) || (
    Echo the file is empty
)
::exit script, you can `goto :eof` if you prefer that
Exit /B


::subroutine
:notEmpty
If %~z1 EQU 0 (Exit /B 1) Else (Exit /B 0)
```

---

Alternatively

notEmpty.bat

```cmd
@Echo OFF
If %~z1 EQU 0 (Exit /B 1) Else (Exit /B 0)
```

yourScript.bat

```cmd
Call notEmpty.bat file.txt
If %errorlevel% EQU 0 (
    Echo the file is not empty
) Else (
    Echo the file is empty
)
```

Comment: This worked great for me. I switched it around so it was called `empty` rather than `notEmpty`, though.