# windows batch: how to check if a text file is blank (the file has an empty line so size is non zero)

Tags: windows, batch-file

Problem with the file is that it sometimes contains a blank line and so the size is not zero. I tried this but as it has an empty line so it returns 1 instead of 0. Any suggestions how to tackle it?

```
set /a varTestPoints=0
for /f %%a in ('type "file.txt"^|find "" /v /c') do set /a varTestPoints=%%a
```

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11225581/how-to-check-if-a-file-is-not-empty-in-batch..possible duplicate question

Comment: Thanks for your help. But this wont solve my problem as my file has one blank line so the size is non zero

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows BAT : test if a specific file is empty](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5483960/windows-bat-test-if-a-specific-file-is-empty)

Comment: check this link here  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5483960/windows-bat-test-if-a-specific-file-is-empty. It appears to be the same question with similar solutions. Hope this helps

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The size can be checked with

```dos
for %%a in ("file.txt") do echo %%~za
```

where `%%~za` is the size of the file referenced by `%%a`

To test if the file only contains blank lines any of these commands can be used

```dos
(for /f usebackq^ eol^= %%a in ("file.txt") do break) && echo has data || echo empty
(for /f "usebackq eol= " %%a in ("file.txt") do break) && echo has data || echo empty
```

If the `for /f` can not find lines with data, it raises an error that can be checked with the `&&` and `||` conditional execution operators

**note** as aschipfl points, in the original code that checks for blank lines the default behaviour in `for /f` that skips lines that start with a semicolon will make the test fail in the lines in the file that start with `;`. Now the code also handles this case by two different ways.

- In the first command, `eol` clause is disabled by assigning it an empty list or delimiters.
- The second command assigns a space to `eol`. While it seems that we simply have changed the problematic character, when the lines are parser by the `for /f` tokenizer, the `delims` clause has precedence over the `eol` (more information [here](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html)), so spaces will be removed as delimiters before they can be seen as `eol`.

Comment: thanks for your quick reply. But as the file contains one blank line the size is shows as 2 KB instead of 0

Comment: @bob, sorry, I thought it was the inverse question. Answer updated

Comment: Thanks a lot. This looks working. I tries it with different variations and it gives desired result. Appreciate your help :)

Comment: I'm afraid the `for /F` approach will fail if a file contains a single line beginning with `;`; `for /F` will not iterate through delimiter-only lines, so adding `eol= ` option (a space) would do it...

Comment: @aschipfl, You are right, thank you. Answer updated.

Comment: Thanks! alternatively, the `eol` option can also be disabled by "hiding" behind `delims`, meaning that one of the delimiter is also given as `eol`, so `"usebackq eol= "` (a space) would work in this case (as the default delimiter is tab+space); this avoids the need of this special undocumented syntax... (if no delimiters are given, the non-quoted syntax is the only way to disable `eol`...)

Comment: @aschipfl, included, thank you. I have to admit that when i need to disable `eol` I don't think and directly go to the escaped delimiter syntax. Anyway, I think that unfortunately  there is a similar level of documentation (and as far as I know almost none official) for the use of escaped  options and the precedence of the `delims` clause.

Comment: Yes, that's true, @MCND; the official documentation does not even mention that there is a default `eol` character...

Comment: Thanks a lot to all of you for giving your time on this.

Answer (score 2):

A file with a single blank line will be 2 bytes long (CR, LF).  You can detect this by checking if the total file size is less than or equal to 2.

```
for %%a in (file.txt) do if %%~za LEQ 2 echo File has no more than 2 bytes
```

This may not work for other files that have more text, but still consist entirely of whitespace and thus appear "empty".  For example, a file containing a single tab followed by a newline would have 3 bytes.  You may be able to adjust your definition of a "blank" file and adapt the code accordingly.

The solution above won't work if your definition of an "empty" file is one that contains only whitespace, regardless of length.  Instead, you can use `for /F` to parse the file.  When reading a file, `for /F` only matches lines that contain non-whitespace characters.  If it finds one, then the file is not "blank".

```
set "fileIsBlank=1"
for /F %%a in (file.txt) do set "fileIsBlank=0"
if %fileIsBlank% EQU 0 echo File has non-blank lines in it..
```

Comment: Thanks Ryan. Your suggestion sounds good. I have tried this as well and looks it works. Do you think its a good idea to use it set lines=0
for /F  %%A in (report.txt) do  SET /A lines=!lines! + 1
echo %lines%

Comment: Thanks Ryan for giving your time. Appreciate your help.

Comment: I'm afraid the `for /F` approach will fail if a file contains a single line beginning with `;`; `for /F` will not iterate through delimiter-only lines, so adding `eol= ` option (a space) would do it...